# Converting between primitive type template specializations

Tags: c++, templates, colors, struct

I'm working on a simple image editor, and I need to be able to convert between pixel types (e.g. 8-bit RGB and 32-bit RGBA). What I have set up to represent pixels is a template struct:

```
template<unsigned int bit_depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt> struct Pixel {};
```

with `PIXEL_FORMAT` being an `enum class`.

The goal is the be able to freely convert between the different pixel formats while working on the image. However, if I try to make a conversion from, for example, 8-bit RGB to 16-bit RGB like so:

```
    Pixel<16, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB> convert_to_16rgb() {
        char red, grn, blu;
        red = ((color & RED_8_BIT) >> 5);
        grn = ((color & GRN_8_BIT) >> 2);
        blu = (color & BLU_8_BIT);

        red = ((red/7) * 31); //(red/(2^3)-1) * ((2^5)-1)
        grn = ((grn/7) * 63);
        blu = ((blu/3) * 31); //these are to maintain the ratio but bring up the actual value

        Pixel<16, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB> _16rgb(red, grn, blu); //Pixel<16, RGB has a 3-uchar c'tor available, but it's down below

        return _16rgb;
    }
```

I get an error stating that `Pixel<16, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB>` was instantiated before it was declared. No problem, just forward-declare it (constructor as well). Then I got an error saying that it was a partial struct and could not be used.

So how would I go about attempting to convert between the various specializations? Make a template function outside of the struct definitions? I would need to specialize for every single combination, though, whereas if I defined two conversions in each specialization, then I could simply "chain" them, converting from one to the next until I reached the result I want (e.g. to convert from 8-bit RGB to 24-bit RGB I could define a _8rgb -> _16rgb conversion and then a _16rgb to _24rgb conversion instead of both a _16rgb and a _24rgb conversion inside `Pixel<8, RGB>`)

By request, a [small example](http://pastebin.com/GLCs4Rw7).

Comment: I assume there is more to struct `Pixel` than `{}` ? Is the template available for expansion before `convert_to_16rgb()` is encountered (including the decl of the latter) ? And can you create a [SSCCE](http://wwww.sscce.org) that actually exhibits the problem?

Comment: @WhozCraig 1) Nope, Pixel is empty and implementation is left to each specialization since the specializations are widely different. Based on what you're saying I'm _assuming_ that was bad form/a bad idea. 2) Not sure what you're asking, could you clarify what you mean by "available for expansion"? 3) Give me a few seconds and I'll have a link to a pastebin page in the question.

Comment: Actually I think you're on the right track if it is laid out as you described. I'll know for sure when I see the code. Certainly you should be able to provide a specialization as you stated, so something else is glitched. The specialization certainly needs to be available for expansion as well, but I assume they're all sitting in the same file anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added a small example if you wanted to look at it. Pretty much all of Pixels.h is left out, only the 8-bit RGB to 16-bit RGB example is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one specialization of Pixel needs the definition of the other for conversion purposes, you need to define all of them before implementing the conversion algorithm. That can be achieved postponing the definition of the conversion function, like shown below, where I edit a piece of code taken out of the example you provided:

```
template<unsigned bit_depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt> struct Pixel {};

template<> struct Pixel<8, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB> {
    unsigned char color;
    Pixel(unsigned char red, unsigned char green, unsigned char blue) {
        color = 0xFF & (((red << 5) & RED_3_3_2) & ((green << 2) & GRN_3_3_2) & (blue & BLU_3_3_2));
    }

    Pixel(unsigned char clr) { color = clr; }

    Pixel<16, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB> convert_to_rgb16();
};

template<> struct Pixel<16, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB> {
    unsigned short color;
    Pixel(unsigned char red, unsigned char green, unsigned char blue) {
        color = (0xFFFF & (((red << 11) & RED_5_6_5) & ((green << 5) & GRN_5_6_5) & (blue & BLU_5_6_5)));
    }
    Pixel(short clr) { color = clr; }
};

Pixel<16, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB> Pixel<8, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB>::convert_to_rgb16() {
    unsigned char red, grn, blu;
    red = ((color & RED_3_3_2) >> 5);
    grn = ((color & GRN_3_3_2) >> 2);
    blu = (color & BLU_3_3_2);

    red = ((red/7) * 31); //5
    grn = ((grn/7) * 63); //6
    blu = ((blu/3) * 31); //5

    Pixel<16, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB> _16rgb(red, grn, blu);
    return _16rgb;
}
```

Note that `convert_to_rgb16` is defined outside of the specialization of Pixel for 8 bits, after the definition of the specialization of Pixel for 16 bits.

Comment: Right, I actually shared this on reddit and got pretty much the exact same response. Adding on to that, I could also make one big function to string them all together. Not sure what the fastest/most efficient way to do that would be.

Comment: what do you mean by "string them all together"?

Comment: For `Pixel<16, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB>` I might have a conversion function to both `Pixel<8, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB>` and `Pixel<24, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB>`. If I want to convert an 8-bit RGB pixel to a 24-bit rgb pixel, what I could do instead of having a conversion for that in the `Pixel<8, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB>` specialization is simply convert up to `Pixel<16, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB>` and then from that to `Pixel<24, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB>`.

Comment: @CaveDweller on my previous answer my implementation of the conversion is "bit-depth agnostic", so it does not require several specializations. Take a look at it, I believe something similar to what I did there would be the most eficient.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the code snippets you provided, I could realize a couple of caveats you should address:

First of all, being `red` an integer strictly smaller than 7, `red = ((red/7) * 31)` will always result in 0, that's because writen this way, you are instructing the compiler to perform an integer division followed by an integer multiplication, that is ignoring decimal fractions.

Now regarding the example you provided, at line 68, I believe `color = (0xFFFF & (((red << 11) & RED_5_6_5) & ((green << 5) & GRN_5_6_5) & (blue & BLU_5_6_5)));` will also always result in 0, that is assuming `RED_5_6_5 & GRN_5_6_5 & BLU_5_6_5 = 0 = 0` as it should be. I believe you meant `color = (0xFFFF & (((red << 11) & RED_5_6_5) | ((green << 5) & GRN_5_6_5) | (blue & BLU_5_6_5)));` here.

Furthermore you use `unsigned short` as a synonym for 'std::uint16_t' and likewise `unsigned int` as a synonym for 'std::uint32_t', what is not required to hold on every platform nor even between different compiler versions on the same platform, so I would strongly recommend using the aforementioned fixed size integers which can be found in .

By your extensive use of constants throughout the code, as well as a fair ammount of code duplication, I can preview that almost certainly you will soon enough encounter a lot of difficulties maintaining your code or even getting it to work. That said, I hope that doesn't sound arrogant of me, but I took the liberty to, aside from fixing the specific problem on which you came here seeking for advice, propose to you a whole new way of dealing with these pixel abstractions.

In the code snippet bellow I rewrote the api for dealing with RGB pixels, keeping the code duplication to what I believe be the minimum, through the use of metaprogramming. You'll realize for example that I didn't have to specialize the class `template<...> struct Pixel` to deal with every possible combination of pixel format and depth, for I left the gory details in a helper class `template<...> struct pixel_tools` which works for any possible depth for a given pixel format, thus reducing replication of code.

I don't pretend my solution is the best for this context, in fact I'm most certain it is not, but I do believe it is an improvement over yours regarding code maintainance. From this point on, if you decide to adopt any of my suggestions, I believe it would be straight forward to extend the idea for the other pixel abstrations with which you are working.

**CAUTION:** it is highly likely that this code snippet contains bugs, I beg your pardon, but I didn't have the time to check it thoroughly.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t bit_depth>
struct underlying_type;

template <>
struct underlying_type<8U>
{
    typedef std::uint8_t type;
};

template <>
struct underlying_type<16U>
{
    typedef std::uint16_t type;
};

template <>
struct underlying_type<32U>
{
    typedef std::uint32_t type;
};

enum class COLOR
{
    RED = 0,
    GREEN = 1,
    BLUE = 2,
    ALPHA = 3
};

enum class PIXEL_FORMAT : char
{
    PALETTE,
    RGB,
    RGBA
};

template<PIXEL_FORMAT fmt>
struct pixel_tools;

template<>
struct pixel_tools<PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB>
{
    //this metafunction avoids the use of #defines, which do get nasty quickly and should be avoided at all costs
    //luckly c++ has strong metaprogramming idioms and boost is your best friend
    //the third argument is necessary because total template specialization is not allowed inside templated structures
    template <COLOR color, std::size_t bit_depth, typename _ = void>
    struct color_mask;

    template <typename _>
    struct color_mask<COLOR::RED, 8U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<8U>::type const value = 0xE0;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_mask<COLOR::GREEN, 8U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<8U>::type const value = 0x1C;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_mask<COLOR::BLUE, 8U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<8U>::type const value = 0x03;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_mask<COLOR::RED, 16U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<16U>::type const value = 0xF800;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_mask<COLOR::GREEN, 16U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<16U>::type const value = 0x07E0;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_mask<COLOR::BLUE, 16U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<16U>::type const value = 0x001F;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_mask<COLOR::RED, 32U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<32U>::type const value = 0xFFC00000;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_mask<COLOR::GREEN, 32U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<32U>::type const value = 0x003FF000;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_mask<COLOR::BLUE, 32U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<32U>::type const value = 0x00000FFC;
    };

    //the third argument is necessary because total template specialization is not allowed inside templated structures
    template <COLOR color, std::size_t bit_depth, typename _ = void>
    struct color_offset_mask;

    template <typename _>
    struct color_offset_mask<COLOR::RED, 8U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<8U>::type const value = 0x05;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_offset_mask<COLOR::GREEN, 8U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<8U>::type const value = 0x02;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_offset_mask<COLOR::BLUE, 8U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<8U>::type const value = 0x00;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_offset_mask<COLOR::RED, 16U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<16U>::type const value = 0x000B;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_offset_mask<COLOR::GREEN, 16U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<16U>::type const value = 0x0005;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_offset_mask<COLOR::BLUE, 16U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<16U>::type const value = 0x0000;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_offset_mask<COLOR::RED, 32U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<32U>::type const value = 0x00000016;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_offset_mask<COLOR::GREEN, 32U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<32U>::type const value = 0x0000000C;
    };

    template <typename _>
    struct color_offset_mask<COLOR::BLUE, 32U, _>
    {
        static typename underlying_type<32U>::type const value = 0x00000002;
    };

    template <COLOR color, std::size_t from, std::size_t to>
    struct depth_conversion_factor
    {
        static constexpr double const value =
                double(color_mask<color, to>::value >> color_offset_mask<color, to>::value)/
                double(color_mask<color, from>::value >> color_offset_mask<color, from>::value);
    };

    template <COLOR color, std::size_t bit_depth>
    static typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type get_color(typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type pixel)
    {
        return (color_mask<color, bit_depth>::value & pixel) >> color_offset_mask<color, bit_depth>::value;
    }

    template <COLOR color, std::size_t bit_depth>
    static void set_color(typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type& pixel, typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type clr)
    {
        //erase current color
        pixel &= ~color_mask<color, bit_depth>::value;

        //set new value
        pixel |= (clr << color_offset_mask<color, bit_depth>::value) & color_mask<color, bit_depth>::value;
    }

    template <std::size_t from, std::size_t to>
    static typename underlying_type<to>::type convert_depth(typename underlying_type<from>::type pixel)
    {
        typename underlying_type<to>::type const converted_red = double(get_color<COLOR::RED, from>(pixel))*depth_conversion_factor<COLOR::RED, from, to>::value;
        typename underlying_type<to>::type const converted_green = double(get_color<COLOR::GREEN, from>(pixel))*depth_conversion_factor<COLOR::GREEN, from, to>::value;
        typename underlying_type<to>::type const converted_blue = double(get_color<COLOR::BLUE, from>(pixel))*depth_conversion_factor<COLOR::BLUE, from, to>::value;

        typename underlying_type<to>::type converted_pixel(0);

        set_color<COLOR::RED, to>(converted_pixel, converted_red);
        set_color<COLOR::GREEN, to>(converted_pixel, converted_green);
        set_color<COLOR::BLUE, to>(converted_pixel, converted_blue);

        return converted_pixel;
    }

    template <std::size_t bit_depth>
    static typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type convert_depth(typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type pixel)
    {
        return pixel;
    }
};

template<std::size_t bit_depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt>
struct Pixel
{
    typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type color;

    Pixel(typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type red, typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type green, typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type blue)
        : color(0)
    {
        pixel_tools<fmt>::template set_color<COLOR::RED, bit_depth>(this->color, red);
        pixel_tools<fmt>::template set_color<COLOR::BLUE, bit_depth>(this->color, blue);
        pixel_tools<fmt>::template set_color<COLOR::GREEN, bit_depth>(this->color, green);
    }

    Pixel(typename underlying_type<bit_depth>::type clr)
    {
        //always a good idea to guarantee a valid value
        pixel_tools<fmt>::template set_color<COLOR::RED, bit_depth>(this->color, pixel_tools<fmt>::template get_color<COLOR::RED, bit_depth>(clr));
        pixel_tools<fmt>::template set_color<COLOR::BLUE, bit_depth>(this->color, pixel_tools<fmt>::template get_color<COLOR::BLUE, bit_depth>(clr));
        pixel_tools<fmt>::template set_color<COLOR::GREEN, bit_depth>(this->color, pixel_tools<fmt>::template get_color<COLOR::GREEN, bit_depth>(clr));
    }

    template<std::size_t new_bit_depth>
    Pixel<new_bit_depth, fmt> convert_depth() const
    {
        return Pixel<new_bit_depth, fmt>(pixel_tools<fmt>::template convert_depth<bit_depth, new_bit_depth>(this->color));
    }
};

template<typename char_t, typename char_traits, std::size_t bit_depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt>
std::basic_ostream<char_t, char_traits>& operator << (std::basic_ostream<char_t, char_traits>& o, Pixel<bit_depth, fmt> const& pixel)
{
    o << '<'
      << std::uint32_t(pixel_tools<fmt>::template get_color<COLOR::RED, bit_depth>(pixel.color)) << ", "
      << std::uint32_t(pixel_tools<fmt>::template get_color<COLOR::GREEN, bit_depth>(pixel.color)) << ", "
      << std::uint32_t(pixel_tools<fmt>::template get_color<COLOR::BLUE, bit_depth>(pixel.color))
      << '>';
}

int main()
{
    Pixel<16U, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB> p16(2U, 5U, 4U);
    Pixel<32U, PIXEL_FORMAT::RGB> p32 = p16.convert_depth<32U>();

    //should output <2, 5, 4> <66, 81, 132> <2, 4, 4> <0, 0, 0>
    std::cout << std::endl << p16 << ' ' << p32 << ' ' << p32.convert_depth<16>() << ' ' << p16.convert_depth<8>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** Compiled and tested using gcc GCC 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease) on an Archlinux x64 box.

Comment: Whoops, thought I fixed the logic there (the & RED_5_6_5 bit).

Comment: Weird, couldn't edit that last comment. Anyway, although it seems interesting it also seems a bit over-engineered. I'll take a little bit from it for sure, but honestly it feels like I have to keep rereading it to figure out what's happening. Also, I did forget that implementations might not be the same, even if there's somewhat of a standard (I mean in Windows `char` is unsigned by default but in Linux it's signed by default).

Comment: I see, then in case you still want to figure out how to fix your specific case, I'll post another answer